# Query Expressions and Lazy Evaluation

Tags: f#

I am hoping to understand how query expressions are really evaluated. I have a situation where I'm using  a query expression to access a large amount of data from a database. I then interact with this data via a GUI. For example the user might supply an additive factor that I want to apply to one column and then plot. What I'm not clear on is how to structure this so that the same data isn't being pulled from the database each time the GUI updates.

For example:

```
let a state= query{...}
let results = a "ALASKA"
let calcoutput y = results |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Temperature + y)
```

or

```
let calcoutput state y = a state |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Temperature + y)
```

I am not clear if these are actually the same code, and if so am I pulling data from the DB each time I execute calcoutput with a different y (it appears so). Should I be casting the "results" sequence as a List and then using that to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Seq.cache function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370430.aspx

Quote: "This result sequence will have the same elements as the input sequence. The result can be enumerated multiple times. The input sequence is enumerated at most once and only as far as is necessary. Caching a sequence is typically useful when repeatedly evaluating items in the original sequence is computationally expensive or if iterating the sequence causes side-effects that the user does not want to be repeated multiple times."